# Python HTML Parsing Between two tags

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

Today I was looking into a small file uploader and I got the following response from the API page.

```
upload_success<br>http://www.filepup.net/files/R6wVq1405781467.html<br>http://www.filepup.net/delete/Jp3q5w1405781467/R6wVq1405781467.html
```

I need to get the part between the two `<br>` tags. I am using Beautifulsoup and this code but it returns None.

```
fpbs = BeautifulSoup(filepup.text)
finallink = fpbs.find('br', 'br')
print(finallink)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot search for text between two tags, no. You *can* locate the first `<br>` tag, then take its [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling), however:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('upload_success<br>http://www.filepup.net/files/R6wVq1405781467.html<br>http://www.filepup.net/delete/Jp3q5w1405781467/R6wVq1405781467.html')
>>> soup.find('br')
<br/>
>>> soup.find('br').next_sibling
u'http://www.filepup.net/files/R6wVq1405781467.html'
```

You *could* use a [CSS selector search](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to search for an [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), then grab the *preceding* sibling; to CSS only the tags are siblings, but to BeautifulSoup the text nodes count too.

The adjacent select is `+` between two CSS selectors, and selects the second of the two; `br + br` would select any `br` tag that comes second.

Together with a parent node (say a specific id or class) that can be a very powerful combination:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <div id="div1">
...     some text
...     <br/>
...     some target text
...     <br/>
...     foo bar
... </div>
... <div id="div2">
...     some more text
...     <br/>
...     select me, ooh, pick me!
...     <br/>
...     fooed the bar!
... </div>
... ''')
>>> soup.select('#div2 br + br')[0]
<br/>
>>> soup.select('#div2 br + br')[0].previous_sibling
u'\n    select me, ooh, pick me!\n    '
```

This picked a very specific text node between two `<br>` tags, in a specific `<div>` tag.