# BeautifulSoup - get string between two tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I would like to capture everything between two HTML tags using `BeautifulSoup`.

This is the snippet of HTML code that I am concerned with:

`<br>NEFS VII &amp; VIII Manager<br>`

So, even with my small understanding of HTML, I can see that I need to capture `<br>` tags and get the content between them. My question appears to be similar to this one ([Python HTML Parsing Between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841687/python-html-parsing-between-two-tags)) where the solution is to use `soup.find('br').next_sibling` but trying that myself I run into the error:

`AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'`.

Here is my relevant code:

```
with open(file_path) as in_f:
    msg = email.message_from_file(in_f) 

html_msg = msg.get_payload(1)   

body = html_msg.get_payload(decode=True)    

html = body.decode()   



br_tags = BeautifulSoup(html).find_all('br')
print("br_tags:", br_tags)
new_tags = BeautifulSoup(html).find_all('br').next_sibling
print("new_tags:", new_tags)
content = br_tags.string
print("content:", content)
```

The command `print("br_tags:", br_tags)` simply prints out 7 `<br/>`'s, all in a list. Trying the `.next_sibling` command as well as the `.string` command both result in the Attribute Error above.

I'm probably misunderstanding how BeautifulSoup is used because I'm a novice with it but I'd appreciate any help solving this, thanks.

EDIT:

Larger chunk of HTML:

```
$0.30</span><o:p></o:p></p></td><td style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt'></td><td style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt'><p class=MsoNormal align=right style='text-align:right'><span style='font-size:10.0pt'>$492.30</span><o:p></o:p></p></td></tr><tr style='height:15.0pt'><td style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:10.0pt'>GB WINTER FLOUNDER</span><o:p></o:p></p></td><td style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt'></td><td style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt'></td><td style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt'><p class=MsoNormal align=right style='text-align:right'><span style='font-size:10.0pt'>95,659</span><o:p></o:p></p></td><td style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt'></td><td style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt'><p class=MsoNormal align=right style='text-align:right'><span style='font-size:10.0pt'>$0.25</span><o:p></o:p></p></td><td style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt'></td><td style='padding:0in 0in 0in 0in;height:15.0pt'><p class=MsoNormal align=right style='text-align:right'><span style='font-size:10.0pt'>$23,914.75</span><o:p></o:p></p></td></tr></table><p style='margin-bottom:12.0pt'><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Linda McCann<br>NEFS VII &amp; VIII Manager<br>
```

Comment: bad example of large chunk - only 2 `br`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error itself tells you that `'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'`. `ResultSet` is type that's got when one uses `find_all()`.

And `AttributeError` appears because you also use in your script `find_all()` instead of `find()`:

```
new_tags = BeautifulSoup(html).find_all('br').next_sibling # yours
new_tags = BeautifulSoup(html).find('br').next_sibling # correct
```

To get all `br` tags text use, for example, this:

```
br_list = []
for i in soup.find_all('br'):
    br_list.append(i.next_sibling)
```

Comment: Ok so that worked. But it only prints one tag pair: `new_tags: <b>Sent:</b>`. Is there a way to get all the pairs? I'd ideally like to put them into a list, if possible, that way I can then scan thru the list looking for certain words (such as `NEFS VII`).

Comment: give a bigger markup example with multiple tags in it

Comment: Ok I'll edit a larger chunk of the HTML into my question

Comment: updated my answer on your request, please check if it suits your needs

Comment: Yeah that was perfect. So it turns out it was a pretty simple fix, I just misunderstood a few small things like the use of `find` and `find_all` and then a simple `for` loop that appends the values to the list. Thanks a ton.